# static method with generics

Tags: c#, generics, static-methods

In java I have a class:

```java
static public class PCB_Node<T extends PCB_Node<T>> implements Iterable<T> {
    public T parent;
    public T first_child;
    public T next_brother;
    
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return get_iterator((T)this);
    }

}


static public <T extends PCB_Node<T>> Iterator<T> get_iterator(T e) {
    ...
}
```

I attempt to do port this to c#, in which I have very little experience.

I defined the class like this:

```cs
public class PCB_Node<T> where T : PCB_Node<T>, IEnumerable<T> {
    public T parent;
    public T first_child;
    public T next_brother;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        return get_iterator((T)this); // << not sure about this, but that also depends on if it is possible
    }
}
```

I have problems with doing the following java line in c#: `static public <T extends PCB_Node<T>> Iterator<T> get_iterator(T e) {`. And I'm not sure if it's even possible, cause so far, I can't find anything about it.
I know I can implement `GetEnumerator` in the class itself instead of redirecting it to some static method, but I prefer it this way.

I guess this is what I want:

`static public IEnumerable<T> get_iterator(T e) where T : PCB_Node<T> {`

Is something like that possible?

Comment: @AluanHaddad No the C sharp class MUST NOT be static, cause I need to be able to make instances.

Comment: sorry I always forget that `static` only applies to nested classes

Comment: @AluanHaddad no problem my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your class declaration is not correct.

Here you are saying that `T` must be a `PCB_Node<T>` **and** implement `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public class PCB_Node<T> where T : PCB_Node<T>, IEnumerable<T>
```

Whereas you want `PCB_Node<T>` to implement `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public class PCB_Node<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : PCB_Node<T>
```

Secondly, this could cause you problems:

```
get_iterator((T)this)
```

Although `T` is a `PCB_Node<T>`, `this`, being of type `PCB_Node<T>` is not necessarily a `T`, which would lead to a runtime exception in this example:

```
class DerivedNode : PCB_Node<DerivedNode> { }

var node = new PCB_Node<DerivedNode>();
var enumerator = node.GetEnumerator(); // InvalidCastException
```

If you want to offload the implementation of `GetEnumerator` to a static method, you would need to declare it like this:

```
public class PCB_Node<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : PCB_Node<T>
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => get_iterator(this);

    public static IEnumerator<T> get_iterator(PCB_Node<T> node)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

If `get_iterator` is declared in another class, you would need to reapply the constraint:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    public static IEnumerator<T> get_iterator<T>(PCB_Node<T> node) where T : PCB_Node<T>
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then call like this:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => AnotherClass.get_iterator(this);
```

Comment: I tried the static method that you did in `AnotherClass` but then I get: "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

Comment: @clankill3r Apologies; typo. You need to declare the method as generic i.e. `get_iterator<T>`.

Comment: damn you are quick with responding :D

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have the following declaration:

```
public class PCB_Node<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : PCB_Node<T>
```

I.e. Your PCB_Node is a IEnumerable, and that T has to be the same kind of PCB_Node

I'm not familiar with static classes in java , but you I would guess you want a regular class.

To implement the IEnumerable you can use a [iterator block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators):

```
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return this
        // add iteration logic
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Personally I would consider separating the iterator from the class, since a tree can be iterated in several different ways. for example by using an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DepthFirst<T>(this PCB_Node<T> root) where T : PCB_Node<T>
{
    yield return root;
    // add iteration logic
}
```